# SQL Azure Premium Experiences

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a white label engine/site generator running on Azure, using SQL Azure Business databases. There are several hundred websites running with good visitor numbers plus lots of bots regularly hitting the sites.

There are also processes running to keep data synchronised hitting the database too.

Generally, it's all working fine but there are too many errors (for my liking) of the following types:

```
[20 per day] System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

[5 per day] System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[2 per week] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 40143. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

[Bad Bots] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 180 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.
```

I am continuously looking to improve the efficiency of queries/the site, etc but I am also expecting to increase the number of sites hosted considerably so there will be more traffic anyway.

I understand that the Premium Azure will offer a better guarantee of capacity, but it is considerably more expensive.

Has anybody had any similar experiences and made the jump to the Azure Premium and would they recommend it?

Comment: Please don't ask questions about recommendations. There is no single correct answer, and you'll likely end up with multiple answers, each based on opinion due to specific circumstances.